# recebendo parametro NULL no fragment de detalhes

Tags: android, mobile, kotlin

Minha classe PokemonItem tem uma Lista de habilidades nela (outra classe), quando vou pegar o "abilities" eu recebo um "null" na minha tela no lugar das "abilities". Alguem pode me ajudar?

```
private fun configDetalhes() {
    Toast.makeText(activity, pokemon.nome, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
   detalhesViewModel.getDetalhes(pokemon.id)
    detalhesViewModel.mResponse.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
        if(it.isSuccessful){
            tv_detalhes_nome_pokemon.text = pokemon.nome
            tv_detalhes_habilidades_pokemon.text = it.body()?.abilities.toString()
        }
    })
}
```

Classe PokemonItem

```
@Entity(tableName = "PokemonItem")
data class PokemonItem(
@PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = false)
val id: String,
@SerializedName("name") val nome: String,
val smallImageUrl: List<PokemonImage>,
val types: List<String>,
val abilities: List<PokemonAbility>

) :Serializable
```

Classe PokemonAbility

```
  class PokemonAbility(
  val name: String,
  val text: String
  )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tenta substituir tua classe PokemonAbility por

```
data class PokemonAbility(
  val name: String,
  val text: String
  ) :Serializable
```